# How to disable HTML autocompletion in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

As I type `const someVariable = someArray[0]`, when I push enter, VSCode automatically converts the whole line to:

`const someVariable = <someArray 0=""></someArray>`

Comment: This is Emmet, search settings for Emmet options. Or press `Ctrl-Z` each time it happens

Answer (score 40):

`"emmet.excludeLanguages": ["typescriptreact"]  // or whatever languages you want to exclude`

like `"emmet.excludeLanguages": ["javascript"]`

Which will stop emmet from working at all in those languages you specify.

**Or** you can also try:

```
"[typescriptreact]": {
   "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"
},
```

or

```
"[javascript]": {
   "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"
},
```

together with

```
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never",
```

to keep emmet features in your language but disable seeing the `abbreviation` and accepting it on `enter`.

Comment: What if I'm just using javascript , not typescript?

Comment: You just replace the `typescriptreact` for whatever language you are using.  I made examples of `javascript` in the answer.

Comment: This annoyed me to no end, and `excludeLanguages` finally fixed it for me, thank you so much!

Comment: While editing html files `dom`  autocompletion keeps popup how to disable those autocompletion? even after add `"emmet.excludeLanguages": ["javascript"]`

Comment: This code looks worth a try, but what file do I put it in / where do I put it to make code understand it?

Answer (score 2):

I think @Mark has the answer to your question.

But, to me it seems that Emmet is doing HTML expansion on your JS code, which it shouldn't be doing, unless your JS is an inline `<script>` element within your HTML file?

So you could leave the settings alone and change file mode when you're in the JS block (press <kbd>F1</kbd>, type `mode` to get the Change Language Mode command, then choose "JavaScript". Do it again to flip back to HTML), or put your JS in a separate file ending in `.js` and link it to the HTML with the `src=` attribute for `<script>`.

Comment: If you're in JSX/TSX land this could also likely be the reason it's happening.