# Disable emmett in functions for styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, emmet

I keep getting emmett autocomplete suggestions even inside the template string used with styled/css/createGloablStyle when using styled-components. Is there a way I can get around to disabling emmett inside the function template string  or maybe at least push it down the suggestions? It's not a problem per see but I have been exploring vscode and want to know if there's a setting that helps.

Image attached below for reference. The body tag I want to disable in autocomplete suggestions.

PS: I don't want to disable emmett globally or even in the file, just in the function scope.

[image: []

Comment: [How to disable HTML autocompletion in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57534494/2873538)

Comment: But I don't want to disable emmett in the file, just inside the template scope