# User snippet placeholder in VS Code don't work since last update

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I've updated visual studio code to the june 2023 release. Since then some of my user snippets do strange things by tabbing, when they contain more than one placeholder ($1, $2, $0).

Example:
I work with mathjax which enables mathematical latex-input in HTML.

```
"ds_sum" : {
        "prefix": "sum",
        "body" : "\\sum_{$1}^{$2}$0",
        "description": "Latex-Summe"
    }
```

Expected result, when I write sum --> tab:
`\sum_{...}^{...}` to be filled with values one after another, jumped by tab key:
`\sum_{k=1}^{n}`

($1: k=1, $2: n, $0: end of the snippet}

The first jump mark $1 is okay ("n=1")
Then I do "tab", and the cursor should move to the second mark $2.

Instead after tab it does an autocompletion that I don't want:
`\<sum_>n=1</sum_>^{}`

Seems as if my snippet becomes dominated by some other snippet (HTML) in the background, or as if the placeholders $1, $2, $0 doesn't work any more.
(Same in any other snippet with more than one placeholder - and $0 doesn't work at all.)

This problem is new to me:
Before the last update everything worked fine.
Maybe there's a preference to be adjusted?

I couldn't find any solution till now (most searche results are older, my problem didn't exist before the last update).

I tried `emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab = true` in the preferences, without success.

(OS: Debian.)

Comment: Your snippet works as is for me.  What is your `Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions` setting out of curiosity?

Comment: Sorry, I see your comment but yet. - Seems as if the problem is solved now - with your (?) help on another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534494/how-to-disable-html-autocompletion-in-vscode - The problem was emmet. Settings: "emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions": "false",
 "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never" - I'll try this in the next days, maybe I'll limit that for html, as you supposed to do. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: Correction: you also need "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true - otherwise emmet will not work in any way. Kind of tricky.

Comment: @starball - I've found it yet, too. Yes, I think it works, thanks!

Comment: I know you found it. please close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try having all the number that you want to tap to inside:
(${1:num1}^${2:num2} ${3:num3) and dont forget to have your snippet code inside body[] like this:`"ds_sum": { "prefix":"sum", "body": [ "Here goes your one line code" ], "description": "Latex-Summe" }` If you write  an example of the mathjax you want in your user snippet just write the exact your math calculation without having your example inside the user snippet json, this way some can embed your wish inside user snippet json format.

Comment: Ah, no - at the first moment it seemed to work, but it didn't (I tested just a little similar example, but not this one). In this case the problem remains the same. I suppose the main reason for the problem is, that some other snippets do overwrite my own.